# Building PortAudio and PyAudio on Mac running Snow Leopard (arch issues)

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio

I'd like to tell you what I've tried and then I'd really welcome any comments you can provide on how I can get PortAudio and PyAudio setup correctly!

I've tried installing the stable and svn releases of PortAudio from [their website](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html) for my Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard. The stable release has a sizeof error that [can be fixed(?)](http://pujansrt.blogspot.com/2010/03/compiling-portaudio-on-snow-leopard-mac.html), but the daily svn release installs fine with `./configure && make &&  make install` (so this is what I'm using). The tests are compiled properly and I can get the binaries to produce output/can read microphone input.

Ok, so then PyAudio has troubles. Installing from [source](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#sources) I get errors about not finding the libraries:

```
mwoods 13 pyaudio-0.2.3$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -DMACOSX=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_portaudiomodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing
_portaudiomodule.c:35:25: error: pa_mac_core.h: No such file or directory
_portaudiomodule.c:679: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PaMacCoreStreamInfo’
_portaudiomodule.c: In function ‘_pyAudio_MacOSX_hostApiSpecificStreamInfo_cleanup’:
_portaudiomodule.c:690: error: ‘_pyAudio_Mac_HASSI’ has no member named ‘paMacCoreStreamInfo’
_portaudiomodule.c:691: error: ‘_pyAudio_Mac_HASSI’ has no member named ‘paMacCoreStreamInfo’
_portaudiomodule.c:692: error: ‘_pyAudio_Mac_HASSI’ has no member named ‘paMacCoreStreamInfo’
_portaudiomodule.c:695: error: ‘_pyAudio_Mac_HASSI’ has no member named ‘channelMap’
_portaudiomodule.c:696: error: ‘_pyAudio_Mac_HASSI’ has no member named ‘channelMap’
_portaudiomodule.c:699: error: ‘_pyAudio_Mac_HASSI’ has no member named ‘flags’

... another 100 lines of this ...

_portaudiomodule.c:2471: error: ‘paMacCoreMinimizeCPUButPlayNice’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_portaudiomodule.c:2473: error: ‘paMacCoreMinimizeCPU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/Qc/Qcl516fqHAWupTUV9BE9rU+++TI/-Tmp-//cc7BqpBc.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I can install PyAudio from [their .dmg installer](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#binaries), but it targets python2.5. If I copy all of the related contents of /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/ to /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ (this includes PyAudio-0.2.3-py2.5.egg-info, _portaudio.so, pyaudio.py, pyaudio.pyc, and pyaudio.pyo) then my python2.6 can recognize it.

```
In [1]: import pyaudio
Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 103, in <module>
    sys.exit(-1)
SystemExit: -1

Type %exit or %quit to exit IPython (%Exit or %Quit do so unconditionally).

In [2]:
```

So this happens because `_portaudio` can't be imported. If I try to import that directly:

```
In [2]: import _portaudio
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_portaudio.so: no appropriate 64-bit architecture (see "man python" for running in 32-bit mode)
```

Ok, so if I `export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes` and then run python again (well, ipython I suppose), we can see it works but with consequences:

```
In [1]: import pyaudio

In [2]: pyaudio
Out[2]: <module 'pyaudio' from '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyaudio.pyc'>

In [3]: import pylab
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/matplotlib-1.0.svn_r8037-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/matplotlib-1.0.svn_r8037-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, validate_toolbar
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/matplotlib-1.0.svn_r8037-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/matplotlib-1.0.svn_r8037-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/matplotlib/colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.4.0.dev7542_20091216-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.4.0.dev7542_20091216-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.4.0.dev7542_20091216-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.4.0.dev7542_20091216-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.4.0.dev7542_20091216-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.4.0.dev7542_20091216-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.4.0.dev7542_20091216-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

We can assume pylab was working before! I spent a while getting this far, but can someone help with this install or lend advice from a successful Snow Leopard install? Sorry for the long post, but I'm notorious for only giving partial information and I'm trying to fix that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to PyAudio's author's speedy response to my inquiries, I now have a nicely installed copy. His directions are posted below for anyone who has similar issues.

> Hi Michael,
>
> Try this:
>
> 1) Make sure your directory layout is
>   like:
>
> ./foo/pyaudio/portaudio-v19/ ./foo/pyaudio/
>
> 2) Build portaudio-v19 from sources,
>   as you have done
>
> 3) cd ./foo/pyaudio/ 4) python
>   setup.py build --static-link
>
> (See the comments at the top of
>   setup.py for more info on
>   --static-link)
>
> If all goes well, inside
>   ./foo/pyaudio/build/lib.macosx-10.6-.../,
>   you'll find the built (fat) objects
>   comprising i386, ppc, and x86_64
>   binaries.  You can also do a "python
>   setup.py install" if you like.
>
> Best, Hubert

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mac 10.5.8 Intel Core 2 duo and hitting the same issue.
The directory layout you need is

```
./foo/pyaudio/portaudio-v19/
./foo/pyaudio
```

The reason is setup.py has the following:
portaudio_path = os.environ.get("PORTAUDIO_PATH", "./portaudio-v19")

alternatively, you should be able to set PORTAUDIO_PATH env variable and get it to work.

Comment: This worked for me.  And perfect timing timing too.  This question has been up for 1/2 yr, and then the day I need this tip, is they day you happened to post and answer.  Thanks!