# Pyaudio, portaudio and mac 10.7.5

Tags: python, macports, portaudio, pyaudio

I'm having trouble installing pyaudio correctly. I have a virtualenv set up for the project. I first tried to install portaudio:

```
sudo port install portaudio
```

which returns:

```
--->  Cleaning portaudio
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

I assume that means it ran fine. Then I tried:

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Which returns:

```
Downloading/unpacking pyaudio
Running setup.py egg_info for package pyaudio

warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'test'
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
Running setup.py install for pyaudio
building '_portaudio' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
src/_portaudiomodule.c:33:25: error: pa_mac_core.h: No such file or directory
...
```

Is that first warning a problem? I'm a bit surprised it's saying no file or directory for portaudio.h. Do I have to do something special to enable my port audio macport installation?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you looked at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893193/building-portaudio-and-pyaudio-on-mac-running-snow-leopard-arch-issues  It's what worked for me.

Comment: I did see that answer. I wasn't sure what to make of the directory layout that it required. Where should that directory go? I did try building from source and got all sorts of errors. I'll try again this weekend with that solution.

Comment: If you're in a virtualenv (or using virtualenvwrapper), pyaudio will not find portaudio during install. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10290595/1386245) helped me out tremendously.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Checkout my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27265703/1119997

Answer (score 6):

```
$ brew install portaudio
$ pip install pyaudio
```

Some missing libraries and such that portaudio provides. Works for Python 2.7 (not sure about other versions)

Answer (score 4):

How about the following:

```
$ sudo port install py27-pyaudio
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-pyaudio
--->  Fetching archive for py27-pyaudio
--->  Attempting to fetch py27-pyaudio-0.2.7_0.darwin_12.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/py27-pyaudio
--->  Attempting to fetch py27-pyaudio-0.2.7_0.darwin_12.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/py27-pyaudio
--->  Installing py27-pyaudio @0.2.7_0
--->  Activating py27-pyaudio @0.2.7_0
--->  Cleaning py27-pyaudio
--->  Updating database of binaries: 100.0%
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
$ python -c "import pyaudio"
$
```

This works for me at least.

Comment: The port installs the package globally, meaning you'll have to copy it manually to your virtualenvs, using something like `cp -r /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/{PyAudio-0.2.11-py3.10.egg-info,_portaudio.cpython-310-darwin.so,pyaudio.py} .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/`

Answer (score 2):

Create a virtual env, activate it:

```
virtualenv env
env/bin/activate
```

Download PyAudio ( latest at the time ):

```
wget -c http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/packages/pyaudio-0.2.8.tar.gz
tar zxf pyaudio-0.2.8.tar.gz
cd PyAudio-0.2.8/
```

Unzip portaudio inside PyAudio folder, rename it to portaudio-v19 and build it:

```
wget -c http://www.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v19_20140130.tgz
tar zxf pa_stable_v19_20140130.tgz
mv portaudio portaudio-v19
cd portaudio-v19
./configure
make
cd ../
```

Back to PyAudio directory:

```
export CFLAGS="-I `pwd`/portaudio-v19/include/ -L `pwd`/portaudio-v19/lib/.libs/"
python setup.py build --static-link
python setup.py install
```

Thats all!

Comment: Worked for me on OS X Sierra

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment above, this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893193/building-portaudio-and-pyaudio-on-mac-running-snow-leopard-arch-issues) answer, but since OP wasn't clear with it, I'm going to try again.  (This is basically just a cut and paste from some notes I made to myself when I was doing this.)

1. This is a build for 32-bit.
2. Download pyaudio, and portaudio (I used 0.2.4, v19).
3. cd portaudio
4. make clean
5. CC="gcc -arch i386" ./configure -enable-static
6. make
7. sudo make install  (maybe not needed if you statically link to it).
8. move portaudio into the PyAudio directory, that is:

   1. cd ..    (out of portaudio)
   2. mv portaudio PyAudio/portaudio-v19   (note need the v19 here)
9. cd into PyAudio and run:

   1. make sure you're in the virtual environment, ie, `source bin/activate`
   2. python setup.py build –static-link
   3. python setup.py install

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had time to work on this project this weekend, but I'll come back to it when I have time to play with it again.

Comment: I tried your solution, I can get up to step 6. When I make it returns: "{standard input}:5:bad register name `%r13'" (about 40 similar errors) then "make: *** [src/common/pa_allocation.lo] Error 1" I don't know what to make of that... should I open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

You can install portaudio with 
$ sudo port install portaudio

and you can install pyaduio with mac installer from http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Answer (score 1):

this will install portaudio which is required for pyaudio:

```
sudo port install portaudio
```

next, look for the appropriate pyaudio macport for your version of python

```
port search pyaudio
```

suppose you are using python27, install pyaudio as such:

```
sudo port install py27-pyaudio
```

References:

[How do I install PyAudio in virtualenv on Mac OS X 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13491401/1463143)

Answer (score 1):

The crucial point is this command：

```
export CFLAGS="-I `pwd`/portaudio-v19/include/ -L `pwd`/portaudio-v19/lib/.libs/"
```

which avoids no such file error.

This solved my problem, thanks very much to @tuxdna.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `pyaudio` setup script (`setup.py`) assumes that all the necessary headers are in `/usr/include`. That is why it works with HomeBrew, and not MacPorts, which typically (and cleanly) puts everything under `/opt/local`.

PyAudio maintainers have relied on HomeBrew, and there is no option combination right now that allows for spelling out where to find the headers. At time of writing, the `setup.py` [source code](https://github.com/jleb/pyaudio/blob/fc7bd1d/setup.py) supports only default values for Mac OS X.

To work with MacPorts, it is cumbersome but enough to create two links for compiling:

```
port install portaudio
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/portaudio.h /usr/include
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/pa_mac_core.h /usr/include
pip install --user pyaudio # Should now compile fine.
```

The links should probably be removed once the install is over.

Tested on Mac OS X 10.10 with Python 2.7 installed with MacPorts.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed this since I wanted to transcribe audio from mic using Google Cloud API. I have Python 3.7 installed in my Mac.

i386 Support is deprecated in recent OSx versions, so solving this requires modifying configure files.

1. Download portaudio source code http://www.portaudio.com/download.html
2. Download MacOSX10.12.sdk https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases and copy it in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
3. Add this lines to portaudio configure file, in order to include MacOSX10.13.sdk and MacOSX10.14.sdk so it doesn't fail

   ```
         elif xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx10.13 Path >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            mac_version_min="-mmacosx-version-min=10.4"
            mac_sysroot="-isysroot `xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx10.13 Path`"
         elif xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx10.14 Path >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            mac_version_min="-mmacosx-version-min=10.4"
            mac_sysroot="-isysroot `xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx10.14 Path`"              
         else
            as_fn_error $? "Could not find 10.5 to 10.14 SDK." "$LINENO" 5
         fi
   ```
4. From your portaudio folder

   ```
   ./configure && make
   sudo make install
   ```
5. Download PyAudio source code (no wheel) https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files
6. Add environment PORTAUDIO_PATH in your .bash_profile with the full path of your downloaded portaudio source code.

   ```
   PORTAUDIO_PATH=/full/path/portaudio
   export PORTAUDIO_PATH
   ```
7. In your downloaded PyAudio source modify setup.py to rename folder portaudio-v19 with portaudio

   ```
   portaudio_path = os.environ.get("PORTAUDIO_PATH", "./portaudio")
   ```
8. Install

   ```
   python3 setup.py install --static-link
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. For me, I downloaded source code from [portaudio](http://files.portaudio.com/download.html) official website.

After compiling and installing, copy the header file `pa_mac_core.h` from `<source code folder>/include` to `/usr/local/include`. The problem was finally fixed.