# I can't import pyaudio?

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to `import pyaudio` i installed `portaudio` with the command `brew install portaudio` and i installed `pyaudio` with `pip` now Im trying to `import pyaudio` and python shows me the error

`Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'`

now when i try to follow the instructions of the answer of [pyaudio could not import _portaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681836/pyaudio-could-not-import-portaudio)

the portaudio tar doesn't have the install file

[PORTAUDIO TAR CONTENENTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqoEa.png)

What can i do?

Python: 3.4

Operating system: Mac OSX the captain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyaudio could not import \_portaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681836/pyaudio-could-not-import-portaudio)

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Anaconda, try the following command. It worked for me:

```
conda install -c anaconda portaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow Step 3 in the link ([pyaudio could not import _portaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681836/pyaudio-could-not-import-portaudio)):

Open Terminal in the directory. Run the following command line one by one.

`./configure`

`make`

`make install # you may need to be root` [link](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/compilation.html)

Then, portaudio will be installed. After this, please follow next steps in the link: Get the dependencies for pyaudio. Uninstall pyaudio and reinstall pyaudio.

Comment: when i reinstall pyaudio shell shows me the error fatal error: 'pa_mac_core.h' file not found

Comment: @ger Please check the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512741/pyaudio-portaudio-and-mac-10-7-5

Comment: @ger Can you do make install with sudo? I found you may need to be root to install correctly: [link](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/compilation.html)

Comment: 'pa_mac_core.h' file not found

Comment: @ger Did you try one of the solutions from the link in my comment? It seems possible duplicate of [error: pa_mac_core.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14512741/9711275).

Comment: i try all the solution and nothing works error: command '/usr/bin/clang'  fatal error: 'pa_mac_core.h'